# Component and service circular dependency? Need refactoring guidance

Tags: angular

I have a DrawerComponent. The premise is to be able to have this drawer sitting somewhere in the app, such as the footer, and to be able to pass different components or templates to it through DrawerService. The solution I implemented works, but I'm concerned about a circular dependency and am wondering how to go about refactoring this. Here's how it works:

1. Singleton DrawerService has a map of DrawerComponents
2. Consuming app places DrawerComponent in a template somewhere (anywhere). DrawerComponent injects DrawerService, and OnInit, it sends the instance of itself to the DrawerService to get placed in the map.
3. Then, any other component can inject the DrawerService and provide a template or component to the Drawer through the service

REPRODUCTION: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kxrdkf?file=src/app/hello.service.ts

My questions are:

- Is this a problem/fundamentally flawed?
- If so, what is the proper Angular approach to this problem (supplying a template to a component that's located in a different area of the app)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're getting circular depedency, it's a design issue. The warning should give you the full path of what the issue is. You may have to rearrange your code to make it work without warnings. You can also leverage interfaces to help suppress things depending on what your code looks like.

Comment: Right, yes this is what I am trying to better understand. Is it a problem that instances of DrawerComponent are kept in a map on DrawerService, and that DrawerComponent injects DrawerService? Or would simply removing the direct references by creating/using an interface as the type on the service so that the drawer.component file itself isn't imported? The typing is the only reason the service imports the component, like setDrawer(drawer: DrawerComponent).

Comment: You need to provide some code for anyone to accurately answer that. I would suggest creating a minimal version of your issue that reproduces your setup so people can help you.

Comment: @mwilson here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kxrdkf?file=src/app/hello.service.ts